# How to migrate my static html web site to Blogger?

Tags: blogger, url, migration

I decided to migrate to blogger.

I used to have pages like www.mysite.com/page.html, but Blogger pages are now like www.mysite.com/p/page.html

When people use the old link which is posted on the forums, they get a 404 error. How can I prevent that?

There's no way to customize URLs in Blogger.

Comment: What is the hosting situation for the old site? You may get a better response over at [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If you have hosting then I would not suggest you to migrate to Blogger, install WordPressin your hosting or youc an go with other CMS if you have sound technical knowledge. As you don't have control over URL structure in blogger after sometime you'll feel to migrate back.

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect the pages on the old site to the new addresses. On the old site, create a file called .htaccess in the root and fill it with entries like this:

```
Redirect 301 /page.html http://www.newsite.com/p/page.html
```

If the file names are the same on both sites, you can avoid typing lots of Redirect rules and do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/p/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will make all `http://www.oldsite.com/page.html` links point to `http://www.newsite.com/p/page.html`.